# How to generate a geographical heat map in MATLAB? (worldwide, country-level granularity)

Tags: matlab, visualization, heatmap

I want to create a geographical heat map like the following in MATLAB:

[image]

Each color is based on a list of country with a percentage associated to each of them:

Country with Codes: % of Hits

- United States (US): 36.29%
- India (IN): 18.24%
- United Kingdom (GB): 12.93%
- Spain(ES): 8.22%
- Australia (AU): 3.32%
- Canada (CA): 3.05%
- Germany (DE): 2.49%
- Netherlands (NL): 1.66%
- Israel (IL): 1.39%
- China (CN): 0.83%

How can I do it in MATLAB?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I looked at http://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping/ and Googled around but I didn't find any easy way to do it. Such kind of maps are commonly used so I'm hoping someone here shares his/her experience.

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to some Geo Science toolboxes, like [this one](http://www.mathtools.net/MATLAB/Earth_Sciences_and_Mapping/).

Also this kind of visualization is trivial in [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). So you may also output the data into a json or so and plot it with D3.js.

Comment: Thanks for the Geo Science link, I looked at some toolboxes but I haven't been lucky so far. Regarding D3.js, I was indeed thinking of using alternatively a web framework as it seems straightforward, such as https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap?hl=en or indeed D3.js, but the issue with web solutions is that I cannot easily generate output files (PNG/PDF/etc). I find it ironic that web frameworks seem to severely beat $4-figure MATLAB for this kind of visualizations, hence my question as I'm hoping there should be somewhere an easy solution for MATLAB.

Comment: Agree. If your goal is an integrated system, I'm afraid there's not so many 3rdparty matlab visualization libs since the internal visualization utilities are good enough(really?). For more specialized application, where you should use more specialized toolkit, you could look for cpp libs, and compile a mex and integrate into your system. E.g. [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/project/casestudies.html). However these libs are too heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help ? the Figure 1 shows some
results similar to your needs ? 
http://www4.fe.uc.pt/spatial/doc/lecture2.pdf

Please note, when I use google API I do save
the results as very high resolution image,
which are good enough for scientific publication.